# Set value on ASP:RadioButton

Tags: asp.net

I know this has been working for me in the past, but my attempt to set the value of my `radiobutton` is  ignored and the value is set to the ID of my radio button.

ASP.Net

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rb" runat="server" />
```

Code behind

```
//Test 1
rb.InputAttributes.Add("value", "foo");

//Test 2
rb.InputAttributes["value"] = "foo";
```

HTML output

```
<input id="rb" type="radio" name="rb" value="rb" />
```

What am I missing here?

Setting the value in ASP.Net markup is working, but I rather do this from codebehind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simple do:

```
rb.Attributes.Add("value", "foo");
```

HTML output:

```
<input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rb" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rb" value="foo">
```

Comment: Also yake a look here http://www.daveparslow.com/2007/08/assigning-value-to-aspnet-checkbox.html

Answer (score 1):

**Code behind :**

```
rb.Attributes.Add("value", "RadioButton");
```

**Output**

```
<input id="rb" type="radio" name="rb" value="RadioButton" />
```

**Reference:**

[Set HTML Attributes for Controls in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7a9d6h4f(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Why posting an answer when someone else post exact the same 17 mins before?